# How to change the color of Chromium (only chrome) downloads bar in a GTK3 theme?

Tags: chromium, gnome-shell, gtk, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS and I installed a custom theme for GNOME but in Chromium app, my download bar color is white (and font color too):

[image: Download bar]

Is there any way to change download bar color editing gtk-2.0/gtkrc file only for Chromium?

Comment: Did you install "Chromium app" as a snap package?

Comment: DK Bose I installed from cmd: apt install chromium-browser

Comment: If you revert to a standard theme does the download bar appear normal? If that happens, your custom theme maybe unsuitable. And chromium-browser use gtk**3**, not gtk2.

Comment: DK Bose yes, if I change to standard theme it back to normal

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128230/chrome-download-messages-not-visible and my answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DK Bose and user3154748 help, I found this solution:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications

perl -i -pe 's/(Exec=chromium-browser)/$1 --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode/g' ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

For the above to be effective, open *Google Chrome > Settings > Appearance > Themes*. There, ensure that Classic is being used and not GTK.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--force-dark-mode` to the chromium-flags.conf.

I think it has to do with the latest update. See this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/b1j0qk/fyi_how_to_fix_chromium_with_dark_themes_since/

Comment: I'm looking for this file, but it doesn't exists.. this link is from 8 years ago

Comment: It says 9 days ago on mine... My Chromium version is the same (73.0.3683.75).

I can't find the file either. I was just hoping it would help as I can't comment yet.

Comment: More details here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1821354

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by @user3154748, I added `--force-dark-mode` to the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` variable in `/etc/chromium-browser/default`, restarted the browser, and it solved the problem. Running Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS (Ubuntu, bionic)