# Chrome download messages not visible

Tags: google-chrome, downloads

On my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop, whenever I download a file in Chrome I cannot read the warnings or button at the bottom of the screen. Like this:

[image]

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: It was the Yaru-Dark theme causing the problem. Thanks. If you add this as a comment I will mark it as the solution. BTW I am using Wayland.

Comment: I just edited the answer to include directions on launching Google Chrome 73 in "dark" mode so that it plays nicely with Yaru-Dark and other dark themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reported issue is seen with various "dark" themes including the dark variants of Adwaita, Materia, and Yaru.

Using a light GTK theme fixes the issue. But it is still possible to use a dark GTK theme and to have the contents of the Downloads bar visible. This requires Google Chrome v73 (or later).

Open *Google Chrome > Settings > Appearance > Themes*. There, ensure that *Classic* is being used and not *GTK*.

Close the browser and launch it like this:

```
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode
```

Now, when you download something, the Download bar appears properly even with a dark GTK theme such as Yaru-Dark.

**Google Chrome's download bar with Yaru-Dark**

[image: Download bar contents visible]

While the dark-mode switches to launch the browser are needed in version 73, they probably will not be necessary in later versions.

Comment: DK Bose please, consider my answer from other question

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe very nice!

Comment: Actually just changing the Google Chrome > Settings > Appearance > Themes to Classic fixed the problem for me. There was no need to use any special command to launch Chrome, just the usual google-chrome-stable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
--force-dark-mode
```

to CHROMIUM_FLAGS variable in /etc/chromium-browser/default do the trick :D !!!
Thanks to this post:
[How to change the color of Chromium (only chrome) downloads bar in a GTK3 theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127629/how-to-change-the-color-of-chromium-only-chrome-downloads-bar-in-a-gtk3-theme)